# Using Ajax gives stale results

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

**EDIT**

My `Ajax` form gets correct `Id` to update a content and a `replace` option.
Submitting is by clicking `<input type="submit" value="submit!" />`.

`Problem`: When I clicked on `submit` I didn't see any update. Second trial gave the expected result. When I refreshed the page the lost record (first hit was successful) was on spot.

**Model**

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Product : AbstractEntity {
    public Product() {
        this.Attachments = new HashSet<Attachment>();
    }
    public String Title { get; set; }        
    public String Commentary { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlacedOn { get; set; }
    public String User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Attachment {
    public String MimeType { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Filename { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HandleError]
public class ProductController : Controller {
    private readonly IDocumentSession documentSession;

    public ProductController(IDocumentSession documentSession) {
        this.documentSession = documentSession;
    }

    public ActionResult ListRecent() {
        return View(ListAll());
    }

    [Audit, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(Guid id) {
        documentSession.Delete<Product>(documentSession.Load<Product>(id));
        documentSession.SaveChanges();
        return PartialView("ProductsList", ListAll());
    }

    [Audit, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            documentSession.Store(product); 
            documentSession.SaveChanges();
        }
        return PartialView("ProductsList", ListAll());
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> ListAll() {
        return documentSession.Query<Product>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Views ('scriptless')**

> Layout

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>        
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/stylesheets/normalize.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/stylesheets/site.core.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="header">[@Html.ActionLink("List", "ListRecent", "Product")]</div>
        <div id="content">@RenderBody()</div>
    </div>        
</body>
```

> ListRecent.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<lamp.DomainLayer.Entities.Product>
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "ListRecent";
    var options = new AjaxOptions {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "productsList"        
    };
}

<h2>List</h2>

@Html.Partial("ProductsList", Model)

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Product", options)) {
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label class="autoWidth">Title</label>
            @Html.Editor("Title")
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Title")
        </p>
        <p>
            <label class="autoWidth">Commentary</label>
            @Html.TextArea("Commentary")
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Commentary")
        </p>
        @* Some fields I have omitted.. *@

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="clear" />

    </fieldset>
}
```

> ProductsList.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<lamp.DomainLayer.Entities.Product>
@{
    var options = new AjaxOptions {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "productsList"
    };
}

<div id="productsList">
    @foreach(var p in Model) {
        <div class="productCard">
            <p class="title"><strong>Title</strong>: @p.Title</p>
            <p class="author"><strong>User</strong>: @p.User</p>
            <p class="date"><strong>Placed on</strong>: @idea.PlacedOn.ToShortDateString()</p>
            <p class="link">@Html.ActionLink("details", "Details", "Product")</p>
            <p class="link">
                @using(Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Product", new { id = p.Id }, options))  {                
                    <input type="submit" value="you!" />
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the unobtrusive ajax library?

Comment: Could you show your view code?

Comment: Where did you include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script? I can't see it anywhere. Is it inside your Layout?

Comment: What's `AppCore.js`? Could it be interfering in some way? What happened when you removed it from your project in order to test whether the problem comes from it?

Comment: You can't see results in all browsers?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov scripts removal didn't help(

Comment: @KamilBędkowski At least in IE 8 I'm experiencing the same result..

Comment: Could you please show your updated code? The one without the useless noise of styles about jQuery UI and AppCore stuff? A fully narrowed down version allowing to reproduce the problem you are talking about. Also it would help if you showed your models.

Comment: the problem you are getting is for Delete OR for Create?

Comment: @ParvSharma the problem is for both.

Comment: you should propably check in the developer console (F12) the return value of your ajax request.. this you you will be able to identity wether the prob is on client side or server side

Comment: Did you verify that inside the Delete action, the ListAll method returns the correct values (with the record deleted)? If not maybe your changes are not committed yet. Are you using some transactions? What's the `IDocumentSession` interface? I suspect that your problem has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC but with your DAL.

Comment: IDocumentSession is an interface that is provided by RavenDB API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Darin was right! I found out that changing my controller code to this one:

```
private IEnumerable<Product> ListAll() {
    return documentSession
       .Query<Product>()
       .Customize((x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults()))
       .ToArray();
}
```

fixes everything.

> .Customize((x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults()))

is the solution!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is IE's  fault (precisely the way,how IE cache AJAX requests). Look here-it could be solution:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-cache-problem-in-ie/

Comment: This was it for me. Works on Chrome but not IE. Using MVC 5, IE 11.0.96 and VS 2015